# How to send parameters while sending JSONArray request

Tags: android, android-volley

I have to access a web service which takes one parameter and gives JSONArray in response. I want to know how to send a POST parameter so that I get response in JSONArray.
 So far I have done the JSON Parsing part correctly and the data is being populated in recycler view. I have tried to Override   `protected Map<String, String> getParams()` as seen in one tutorial but that override is showing an error `"Method does not override method from its superclass"`.  Kindly see my code and guide me on how to implement it correctly.

```
public void JSON_WEB_CALL(){

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }


                @Override //This Override is showing an error "Method does not override method from its superclass"
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("param1", "one");
                    params.put("param2", "two");
                    return params;
                }

            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsArrRequest);

}



public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        DataModel GetDataModel = new DataModel();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataModel.setId(json.getString("PRODID"));

            GetDataModel.setPlateNo(json.getString("GRADE"));

            GetDataModel.setPlateCode(json.getString("COLOR"));


        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DataAdapterClassList.add(GetDataModel);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new NewRecyclerViewAdapter(DataAdapterClassList, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

    if (array.length()!=0) {
        SHOW_ALERT(array);
        sendNotification(recyclerView, array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your calling a POST request so you have use `Request.Method.POST` instead of  `Request.Method.GET`
Please use the code below,

```
public void JSON_WEB_CALL(){

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }


                @Override //This Override is showing an error "Method does not override method from its superclass"
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("param1", "one");
                    params.put("param2", "two");
                    return params;
                }

            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsArrRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `params` first with key value pair using `Hashmap` and pass it

```
    HashMap<String ,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("key",value);

JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, HTTP_SERVER_URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
  //....
}
```

Comment: Did you try this?